# Может ли Log4net записывать логи в бинарном формате?

Tags: логирование, log4net

Возникла необходимость писать логи в бинарном формате, т. е. писать просто массив байтов. Может ли log4net записывать в таком формате? Я искал искал, нашёл только то, что он записывает байты, но в текстовый файл.

Comment: Что такое логи в бинарном формате для вас? Цифры и буквы - это тоже бинарные данные ..

Comment: Например, берёшь BinaryWriter и в файл пишешь.